# SQL Server performance: one-to-one join, or select within select?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a schema which involves customers, facilities for each customer, projects for each facility, and items for each project.

I want to know if there is a general rule of thumb concerning the performance of listing the customer for each item. One way I think is common is:

```
SELECT
    item.iteminfo
    customer.customerinfo
FROM 
    item
INNER JOIN 
    project ON item.projectid = project.projectid
INNER JOIN 
    facility ON project.facilityid = facility.facilityid
INNER JOIN 
    customer ON facility.customerid = customer.customerid
WHERE 
   (item filtering criteria)
```

Each table is indexed on their primary and foreign keys.

However, in benchmarking, I found this to be slightly more performant:

```
SELECT
    item.iteminfo
    (SELECT TOP 1 customerinfo
     FROM customer
     WHERE customerid = (SELECT TOP 1 customerid
                         FROM facility
                         WHERE facilityid = (SELECT TOP 1 facilityid
                                             FROM project
                                             WHERE project.projectid = item.projectid)
                       )
     )
FROM 
    item
WHERE 
    (item filtering criteria)
```

Is there a reason for this difference? If so, how can I utilize it to make other queries similarly more performant?

Thanks!

Comment: No way to know for certain w/o seeing the actual execution plans for both queries.

Comment: Personal preference, the minimal gain that you may achieve from doing this the second way is cancelled out by the fact it is far less readable / maintainable.

Comment: Joins definitely should have better performance. How much rows your tables have? Try execute queries with millions of rows.

Comment: Are the **foreign key columns** involved in your JOINs all properly indexed? That can make quite a difference

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In questions about SQL, it's always good to include DDL+DML for sample data. I'll add a script to the end of this post that will use CTEs to generate a bunch of test data.

After a few tests, I find the joins are more performant.

If you run the 2 queries against each other for a single item id (where item.itemid = 500, e.g.), each query has 50% cost.

[image: itemid = 500]

If you use a range - in this case, itemid between 200 and 8000, the query cost starts to really favor the joins (19% to 81%), and the joins execute faster consistently.

[image: itemid between 200 and 8000]

I check the speed like this:

```
declare @start datetime
set @start = getdate()

Query 1

select getdate() - @start
set @start = getdate()

Query 2

select getdate() - @start
```

If you increase that range to itemid between 200 and 80000, you see even more separation - the query cost is like 5% to 95% in favor of the joins, and the joins excute ~330 MS in my scenario vs ~420 MS for the alternative query.

[image: itemid between 200 and 80000]

Is there something real unique about your where clause? Maybe there's a sargability issue or something.

Here's the DDL/DML, which creates 100 customers, ~1000 facilities, ~10000 projects, ~100000 items:

```
create table customer (customerid int primary key,customerinfo varchar(25))
create table facility (facilityid int primary key, customerid int foreign key references customer(customerid))
create table project (projectid int primary key, facilityid int foreign key references facility(facilityid))
create table item (itemid int primary key, iteminfo varchar(25), projectid int foreign key references project(projectid))
GO

;with cte as
(select 1 as id, 'customer' + cast(1 as varchar(5)) as info
union all
select cte.id + 1 as id, 'customer' + cast(cte.id + 1 as varchar(5))
from cte 
where cte.id < 100)
insert into customer select id, info from cte
option(maxrecursion 100)
GO

;with cte as
(select 1 as id, 1 as customerid
union all
select cte.id + 1, ((cte.id + 1) / 10) + 1
from cte 
where cte.id < 999)
insert into facility select id, customerid from cte
option(maxrecursion 1000)
GO

;with cte as
(select 1 as id, 1 as facilityid
union all
select cte.id + 1, ((cte.id + 1) / 10) + 1
from cte 
where cte.id < 9989)
insert into project select id, facilityid from cte
option(maxrecursion 10000)
GO

;with cte as
(select 1 as id, 1 as projectid, 'item' + cast(1 as varchar(5)) as iteminfo
union all
select cte.id + 1, ((cte.id + 1) / 10) + 1, 'item' + cast(cte.id + 1 as varchar(5))
from cte 
where cte.id < 99889)
insert into item select id, iteminfo, projectid from cte
option(maxrecursion 0)
GO
```

Comment: Very good answer. I would only change the first sentence - In questions about sql, it's Always good to include DDL+DML for sample data.

Comment: @ZoharPeled Great feedback - thank you - adjusted my answer accordingly.